# Why does value="string-value" work with input type="time", but not bind-value="string-value"

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I'm working on a simple website to try out some Blazor (I'm a rookie). I have created a binding with a string value "08:00" and bind i to a input field as shown:

```
<input @bind-value="@StartValue" @bind-value:event="onchange" class="col-sm-1" type="time"/>
@code {
public string StartValue { get; set; } = "08:00";
}
```

This generates the error "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime'". However, when I remove my binding and create my input as following: it works fine.

```
<input value="08:00" class="col-sm-1" type="time"/>
```

Any idéeas why there's a difference? It doesn't make sense to me to use a DateTime, I would agree if I could use a TimeSpan but that doesn't work either.

Comment: have you tried using `bind` instead of `bind-value` ?

Comment: It seems to return the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@bind-value`, you are binding to a string-type, which won't work with type="time".

With `value`, you entered a correct type "time", and not a string.
When you would enter a string like 'foo', it will not work.

Comment: Thanks @Inktkiller. But the type seems to be a full DateTime when I post the value. If I'm to change my code and supply a full DateTime to my bind-value. Do you know what is the best practise? Should I enter DateTime.Now before my timepoint (since the input doesn't accept just a TimePoint)?

Answer (score 1):

I tried input type time with TimeSpan and got the following compilation error:
`Error    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.TimeSpan' to 'System.DateTime'`

Blazor maps certain types of `<input />` to certain types of CLR types. 
The reason for this could be to reduce unwanted type and conversion errors, miss behaviors (?).

In the official docs of Blazor this is mentionet in "pieces" like:

> When the component is rendered, the value of the input element comes from the CurrentValue property. When the user types in the text box and changes element focus, the onchange event is fired and the CurrentValue property is set to the changed value. **In reality, the code generation is more complex because @bind handles cases where type conversions are performed.** In principle, @bind associates the current value of an expression with a value attribute and handles changes using the registered handler.

[Link to the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#data-binding)

You could use `DateTime` and provide a formater like:

```
<input @bind="StartDate" @bind:format="yyyy-MM-dd" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you @Zsolt!
I solved it like you suggested it with using a DateTime property as you suggest. It's probably a good thing that Blazor demands correct types. 
On my case when I want to use only time and not dates, I find it weird that I have to use a DateTime. I would prefere to only use a TimeSpan instead. 
However, the problem is solved and I got to learn a thing or two! So I'm happy and thankful.